# user profile image in mac os x

Tags: image, macos, account, user-profile

Where is the user profile image saved in Mac OS X 10.8?
I need it because I've lost every copies of it, but I'm sure it's saved in the computer, but where? I haven't been able to find anything online about it!

In the option, where I can select the method to choose image, one choice there is "make a photo with webcam". I selected it but I don't know where it was saved.